# Gridview On Row Command

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to validate a `GridView` using its `onRowCommand`.
When I select a button, it needs to validate that rows `delivery date` and shows an error message inline if invalid.

Currently, my `GridView` is setup like this:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvDistribution" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="1000px" DataKeyNames="id" AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="gvDistribution_PageIndexChanging" PageSize="5" OnRowCommand="gvDistribution_OnRowCommand" OnRowDataBound="gvDistribution_RowDataBound">
       <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
           <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Beneficiary Name"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="packingDate" HeaderText="Packing Date" DataFormatString="{0:dd/M/yyyy}"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="deliveryDate" HeaderText="Delivery Date" DataFormatString="{0:dd/M/yyyy}" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" ItemStyle-Width="120px">
                      <ItemTemplate>
                           <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:ButtonField CommandName="View" Text="View Details" />
                <asp:ButtonField CommandName="Action" Text="Action" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" ItemStyle-Width="120px">
                   <ItemTemplate>
                         <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                   </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
           </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

And the code behind for `GridView` `onRowCommand`:

```
protected void gvDistribution_OnRowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        int rowNo = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        string distributionID = this.gvDistribution.DataKeys[rowNo].Value.ToString();
        if (e.CommandName == "View")
        {
            Response.Redirect("PackingDetails.aspx?id=" + distributionID);
        }
        else if(e.CommandName == "Action")
        {
            DistributionPacking distPack = new DistributionPacking();
            distPack = packBLL.getDateDetailByDistributionID(distributionID);
            DateTime deliveryDate = distPack.deliveryDate;

            foreach (GridViewRow g in gvDistribution.Rows)
            {
                if (deliveryDate > DateTime.Today)
                {
                    Label lblError = (Label)g.FindControl("lblError");
                    lblError.Text = "Delivery date has not reach yet!";
                }
                else
                {
                    bool result = packBLL.updateDeliveryStatus(distributionID);
                    if (!result)
                    {
                        //Call the retrieve all distributions without any filtering again
                        List<DistributionPacking> allDistribution = new List<DistributionPacking>();
                        allDistribution = packBLL.getAllDistribution();
                        gvDistribution.DataSource = allDistribution;
                        gvDistribution.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The issue is that when the `delivery date` gets validated, an error message is displayed in *every row*, not just the one needing validation.
Could someone show me how to force only one message in the validated row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then replace the loop beginning with

```
foreach (GridViewRow g in gvDistribution.Rows){}
```

with

```
if(gvDistribution.SelectedRow != null)
{
    if (deliveryDate > DateTime.Today)
    {
        Label lblError = (Label)gvDistribution.SelectedRow.FindControl("lblError");
        lblError.Text = "Delivery date has not reach yet!";
    }
    else
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I fixed by by using the code in edited portion. Yours work also. Thanks alot